# Mobile Recorder launced and closed app automatically

Tags: appium-android, katalon-recorder

I am using Katalon mobile recorder to capture mobile objects.
The app launced sucessfully - splash screen - landed at main page.
Then app is cloased with below error displayed at katalon.

Any idea what are those errors?

I am not sure if this is Katalon or Appium or any missing configuration at JAVA?

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WSG61453', ip: '192.168.6.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:381:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WSG61453', ip: '192.168.6.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.components.impl.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.runAndWait(ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.java:49)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.mobile.objectspy.components.MobileLocalAppComposite$12.run(MobileLocalAppComposite.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WSG61453', ip: '192.168.6.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:381:37)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WSG61453', ip: '192.168.6.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:208)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:217)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:239)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.execute(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:84)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:85)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.SwipeableAndroidDriver.<init>(SwipeableAndroidDriver.java:24)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:498)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.appium.driver.AppiumDriverManager.createMobileDriver(AppiumDriverManager.java:480)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.internal.MobileDriverFactory.startLocalMobileDriver(MobileDriverFactory.java:527)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.mobile.objectspy.dialog.MobileInspectorController.startMobileApp(MobileInspectorController.java:195)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.mobile.objectspy.components.MobileLocalAppComposite$12$1.call(MobileLocalAppComposite.java:479)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.components.impl.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.startThreadAndWait(ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.java:36)
    at com.kms.katalon.composer.components.impl.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.runAndWait(ProgressMonitorDialogWithThread.java:48)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor$1.createSession(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:186)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:53'
System info: host: 'WSG61453', ip: '192.168.6.97', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: SwipeableAndroidDriver
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot start the 'com.test.OneApp.sample' application. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting. Original error: 'crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' or 'com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView' never started. Visit https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md for troubleshooting
    at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:804:9)
    at asyncHandler (C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:381:37)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the correct start activity for you application in the DesiredCapabilities, so the katalon cannot reach to the app main page.
This is what you defined as `appActivity`:
`crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView` or `com.test.OneApp.sample.crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView`.

as you see this activity is only launch SplashScreen, so this is the root cause.

Try to find the start activity via apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csdroid.pkg) and then define as **appActivity** DesiredCapability here: `Project Setting / Execution / Default / Mobile / Android`.

I suggest define all the mandatory desired capabilities there.

Comment: I have defined appWaitActivity = com.test.OneApp.samplecrc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView but still seeing the same error.

Comment: by using the app package name, i can see the same and only activity name com.test.OneApp.samplecrc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.SplashScreenView

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
added below at Katalon - project settings

```
AppActivity = crc64ca4b5f30746aea4d.MasterView
```